# Ratings on List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, item, rating, like

I have added Ratings enabling on a item tracking list however I cannot see how you can actually rate a item. We want the ability when someone is in a list item they can like it (once) and then preferably on the main list we can see how many likes on item has. I can see this in my columns but I cannot obviously see how to put this on the main list. I am using SharePoint online.

[image: Columns]

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in using Ratings or Likes?  Your question title says Ratings.

I think you can only see your own Rating at present.  Ask someone else to help test it.  If you give a rating of 5, your colleague gives a rating of 1, it should show an average score of 3 out of two Ratings.

In the pictures below I once set up a demo for myself to see how this works.  The Ratings you see are just based on my Ratings.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure My Sites is configured. Ratings and Likes will not work without that.

Then in List Settings, enable rating and the type.

[image: List Settings]

---

[image: Rating Options]

---

This will automatically add the columns to your list.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for this. I am trying to use likes ideally. I can't see a way that you can actually like the item. I have put the rating settings on.

Comment: The second option in the ratings settings page should have a radio button for likes. You may want to try it with a new empty list, putting the columns in manually may have changed how the settings appears.